# Filter brightness function in css doesnt work on Edge, IE 11, and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a mobile version, I cant change the color of the logo black to white using the filter property in CSS. It works in Chrome, but not in IE v11, Firefox, and Edge. Even the filter property supports all browsers? I also tried the javascript to make it work - no success. I'm not sure `onload` function in the body tag is a good idea?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/d5huxtjs/2/)

CSS

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(0) invert() !important;
-ms-filter: brightness(0) invert() !important;
-moz-filter: brightness(0) invert() !important;
-o-filter: brightness(0) invert() !important;
filter: brightness(0) invert() !important;
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="http://www.svrs.com"><img src="imgs/logo-svrs.png" class="logo-svrs" alt="Sorenson VRS"></a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("logo").style.filter = "brightness(300%)";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.WebkitFilter = "brightness(300%)"; 
    document.getElementById("logo").style.msfilter = "brightness(300%)";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.mozFilter = "brightness(300%)";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.oFilter = "brightness(300%)"; 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: according to https://caniuse.com/#search=filter the filter function does not work in IE11 and just partially in Edge. So your question is expected

Comment: IE11 does not support `filter` at all.

Comment: Works in FF is you use `invert(100%) and change the order - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZaXZmb

Comment: @Paulie_D - yeah, that worked on FF except for IE11. Guess I'm going to replace the color of the image to white in Photoshop - thanks!